# JPA2, LEFT JOIN, Criteria API

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, eclipselink

I have the following situation SQL that I need to implement into my criteria builder for dynamic query creation.

```
select t1.ticketnr 
from tbl_ticket t1 
left join tbl_tickets_updates t2 on t1.ticketnr = t2.ticketnr 
where t1.description ilike '%EXAMPLE%' or t2.description ilike '%EXAMPLE%';
```

In my code I have the following:

tbl_ticket = Tickets.class
PK = ticketnr

tbl_tickets_updates = TicketsUpdates.class and TicketsUpdatesPK.class
PK = ticketnr, updatedby, timeofupdate

```
        CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Tickets> query = builder.createQuery(Tickets.class);
        EntityType<Tickets> type = em.getMetamodel().entity(Tickets.class);
        Root<Tickets> root = query.from(Tickets.class);
        List<Predicate> predicatesAnd = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
...
    if (text.length() != 0) {
                    predicatesAnd.add(builder.or(
                            builder.like(
                            builder.lower(
                            root.get(
                            type.getDeclaredSingularAttribute("description", String.class))), "%" + text.toLowerCase() + "%"),
                            builder.like(
                            builder.lower(
                            root.get(
                            type.getDeclaredSingularAttribute("summary", String.class))), "%" + text.toLowerCase() + "%")));
                    Join<Tickets, TicketsUpdates> tupdates = root.join("ticketnr", JoinType.LEFT);
                    predicatesAnd.add(builder.like(builder.lower(tupdates.get("description").as(String.class)), "%" + text.toLowerCase() + "%"));
                }
```

My code is failing at the Left Join with: **java.lang.IllegalStateException: CAN_NOT_JOIN_TO_BASIC**

I believe this is happening due to having a separate class for the composite PK, but so far I have not found a way to implement this properly.

Any ideas?

Comment: This SQL query doesn't make sense. group by is only useful when the select clause contains aggegate functions, like sum, count, avg, min, max.

Comment: you are right, the group by is extra. Still my issue is with left join.

Comment: in JPQL/Criteria, you can only join on associations between entities. You'd better use JPQL for such a static query. And if you really want to use JPA, use the metamodel-generated classes.

Comment: Should I assume then, that what I'm doing is not possible with my current implementation? Both classes are entities and in this case I really need to implement metamodel-generated classes?? :/ I'll give a try anyway since I want to use JPA to keep it consistent with what I currently have.
Thanks

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the actual working request (which would be much clearer in JPQL) and the entities. But if you don't join using an association, it won't work. If you used the metamodel, you would at least benefit from the type safety it brings.

Comment: You need to use the relationship name, not the foreign key column name.  Judging by the SQL and the exception, you are using ticketnr as the foreign key, but named the relationship in your entity something slightly different.  You need to use the objects in JPA, not the database field names

Comment: @Chris thanks that was indeed the problem!!! I performed two changes as the join has to be done in a separate Root it seems. :/ At least my error is now gone and as soon as I fix the query I'll put the answer.
Thanks a lot !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment of Chris, I was providing column name instead of the relationship name from the Entity Class ( marked as Mapped in the entity class )

```
 CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
            CriteriaQuery<Tickets> query = builder.createQuery(Tickets.class);
            EntityType<Tickets> type = em.getMetamodel().entity(Tickets.class);
            EntityType<TicketsUpdates> typeTU = em.getMetamodel().entity(TicketsUpdates.class);
            Root<Tickets> root = query.from(Tickets.class);
            Root<TicketsUpdates> rootTicketsUpdates = query.from(TicketsUpdates.class);

            Join<Tickets,TicketsUpdates> tupdates = rootTicketsUpdates.join("tickets");
```

I had to add the second from ( it was missing ) and change my query to:

```
if (text.length() != 0) {
                predicatesAnd.add(builder.or(
                        builder.like(
                        builder.lower(
                        root.get(
                        type.getDeclaredSingularAttribute("description", String.class))), "%" + text.toLowerCase() + "%"),
                        builder.like(
                        builder.lower(
                        root.get(
                        type.getDeclaredSingularAttribute("summary", String.class))), "%" + text.toLowerCase() + "%"),
                        builder.like(
                        builder.lower(
                        tupdates.get(
                        typeTU.getDeclaredSingularAttribute("description", String.class))), "%"+text.toLowerCase()+"%")
                        ));
            }

    query.orderBy(builder.desc(root.get("startdate")));
    query.distinct(true);
```

Now all works as expected!